# Python module level logging configuration

Tags: python, logging

I have read from python docs https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial that the best way to configure module level logging is to name the logger:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I the main application logging works fine:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')  
    # create logger  
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

However in another module when I set the logger in the module scope:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

the logger does not log anything. When I create the logger within a method logging works fine:

```
class TestDialog(QDialog, Ui_TestDialog):  
def __init__(self, fileName, parent=None):  
    super(TestDialog, self).__init__(parent)  
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  
    logger.debug("--_init_() "+str(fileName))
```

Then I would need to use the self.logger.. formatting to get a logger in all methods in the class - which I have never seen before. I tried to set the logging.conf to log where the call is comming from:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,fileLogger
...
[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(module)s - %(lineno)d - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

However when the logger is set in the module scope logging still doesn't work even with this configuration.

I also tried:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('root')
```

at the start of a module, again no logger. However If I use:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('fileLogger')
```

at the start of a module, logging works fine and with config file above I can see which module the call is comming from.

Why is configuring logger using **name** not inheriting it's config from root?
Why does configuring using root not work while using fileHandler does, when both root and fileHandler are configured in the logging.conf file?

Comment: side note: In order to get the "root" logger, do just  ```logger = logging.getLogger()```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid surprises, use `disable_existing_loggers=False` in your `fileConfig()` call, as documented in [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) of the docs.

You should never need to use a `self.logger` instance variable - module level loggers should be fine.